# AJAX Callback check for exact input in registration field

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I got a WordPress Plugin (UserPro) to handle registrations one my website.

In the registration form I need a text field, which needs to specifically match one of several possible options. I have put the AJAX check callback into the frontend, but don't know what to put into the backend ajax.php:

```
case 'charge_validate':
if (fieldvalue is not one of these - dont know how to write that correctly) {
$output['error'] = __('Please give a valid response.','userpro');
}
break;
```

What do I need to put into the if () part?

Thanks for any help!

Best regards,
One guy who knows nothing at all about Ajax :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where your required values are stored or what `fieldvalue` is but the code below is a typical way to check for a required value:

```
$allowedVals = array('something', 'anotherthing');
if (!in_array($_GET['fieldvalue'], $allowedVals)){
    $output['error'] = __('Please give a valid response.','userpro');
}
```

Comment: perfect! this helped me a ton. thanks you both and have a great weekend!